# Responsive, TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, responsive

[image]I want to return a screen responsive, well only the section that shows loaded images.
How can I change it, since in my code I entered a [height] and a [width] to give them a measure, but I would like them to be adjusted automatically, if that is done in the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make responsive either using bootstrap col or by using media query
If it's possible to rewrite your html code and adding col it will be good

```
  <div class="row">
      <div *ngIf="" class="col-sm-12>
    /* .... */
      </div>
   </div>
```

Or using media query

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait),
only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  #gallery {
    width: 50% !important;
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 450px) and (max-width: 1023px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  #gallery {
    min-height: 400px;
    // max-height: 50% !important;
  }
  }

  @media (max-width: 450px) {
 #gallery {
    // max-height: 50% !important;
    // width 
  }
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much, I solved it using only "%" in height and width

Comment: great! so pls make the answer as answered :) @AnfonyLagunaAv